# Read .dat file in c#

Tags: c#, binary-data

i want to read a .dat file that have following conditions:-

```
First name offset                       21
First name format                       ASCIIz 15 chars + \0
Middle initials offset                  37
ID offset                               -8
ID format/length                        Unsigned int (4 bytes)
```

so help me for sorting this issue in c#.

Thanks in advance.

Gurpreet

.dat file

```
 (                                           ÿ   /          rE            ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ     XÙþÞ¦d e e   Mr.        Sam                             Ascott          Sam             9209 Sandpiper Lane                                                               21204      410 5558987         410 5556700 275                                        MM229399098 (¬                                                                                                      Þ                                    e   Ü¤•Þ„                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  œÔ£ÝáØáØ  ’Þ[Þ    €–˜ ä–˜                [Þ          ¶ Norman Eaton                  Friend of Dr. Shultz          Removal of #1,16,17 & 32 öÜÝ)Ý         Ä                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           d                                                                                     01 21 21 21  e   101                                                 22099                                                                                                                                                                                                    XÙþÞ¦d e .  Mrs.       Patty                           Baxter          Patty           3838 Tommytrue Court                                                              21234      410 2929290         410 3929209                                            FM218798127    HAY FEVER                                                                                             Þ                                    .  „¤¢Þè                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 _ÐÍÝBÒBÒ  ’ÞÝ    €–˜ ä–˜                ÍÝ          f   Joanne Abbey
```

Comment: i update that please check.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here is a tutorial how to use BinaryReader for this purpose:

http://dotnetperls.com/binaryreader

Comment: @Gurpreet Read 21 bytes and throw them away, then read 16 bytes and you have the first name. And no more caffeine for you today.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Jet [OleDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288452%28VS.71%29.aspx) to query .dat files:

```
var query = "select * from file.dat";
var connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\file.dat;Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=NO;FMT=FixedLength\"");
```

See this link:

- Code Project. [Read Text File (txt, csv, log, tab, fixed length)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ReadTextFile.aspx)

And check these:

- [Reading a sequential-access file](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/File-Stream/Readingasequentialaccessfile.htm)
- [DAT files in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/readbinary.html)
- [Read a file in C#](http://fullycoded.com/?p=221)
- [BinaryReader Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx)
- Jon Skeet. [Reading binary data in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/readbinary.html)

Comment: but i want to read the firstname, lastname , id etc using their offset like First name offset 21 ,Middle initials offset 37 etc

Answer (score 1):

As said, have a look at the [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx)

```
//Example...
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
string name = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(reader.ReadBytes(8));
int number = reader.ReadInt32();
```

Comment: Please don't paste the same comment here... I understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

`my .dat file content - "  €U§µ­PÕ  „ÕG¬u   "`
[click here to see the content of my .dat file in Notepad and hexa editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ioml1.png)

```
            string fileName = @"W:\yourfilename.dat";
            //Read the binary file as byte array            
            byte[] bHex = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

            //Create string builder for extracting the HEX values
            StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();

            //initialize the int for 0
            int i = 0;
            // check it worked

            //Reverse the HEX array for readability
            foreach (char c in bHex.Reverse())
            {
                i++;
                // 12 to 21 byte in the reverse order for interseted value in ticks"

                if (i > 12 && i < 21)
                    st.Append(Convert.ToInt32(c).ToString("X2"));

            }

            // Convert HEX to Deciamal
            long Output = Convert.ToInt64(st.ToString(), 16);

            //Convert ticks to date time
            DateTime dt = new DateTime(Output);

            //Write the output date to console
            Console.Write(dt);
```

Final de-crypt binary content to data-time.
[final output of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27fJ8.png)